# Content not visible and div stretches

Tags: css, html, margin, padding

Here's my html. The problem I am having is that the 'box1' divs do not even display and the 'nav' bar extends itself. I have no idea why...

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="selected" href="link1">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="link2">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="link3">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="link4">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="link5">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div> <!--#nav-->
<div id="content">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="box1">
            TEXT
        </div> <!--#box1-->
        <div class="box1">
            IMAGE
        </div> <!--#box1-->
    </div> <!--#wrapper-->
</div> <!--#content-->
```

And the CSS...

```
#nav {
    background-color: #000;
}
#nav ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}
#nav li {
    display: inline;
}
#content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 720px;
}
.box1 {
    width: 40%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 6.33%;
}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CZ5UB/
I have the code set up in a fiddle. Can you explain a little more as to what is wrong in what you see

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bmvrR/ is this what you are after? it is unclear from your question.

Comment: The 'nav' divs height seems to increase... and any content after the 'nav' div don't display at all. I think it may be a padding issue but i'm unsure

Comment: @luke2012 That's almost it, however I want the two 'box1's to be centered. How did you manage to get it to display like that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bmvrR/1/

is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Take a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/bmvrR/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
.box1 {
    width: 40%;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 6.33%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Preview >> http://jsfiddle.net/XJA4T/